# rewrite flag [L] is not working

Tags: .htaccess

This is my .htaccess file i just want to rewrite the page from one url to another.But it moved 404 page

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/article/([^/]+)$ /index.php?option=com_vendorsearch&view=article&title=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/polls/([^/]+)$ /index.php?option=com_vendorsearch&view=polls&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/coupons/([^/]+)$ /index.php?option=com_vendorsearch&view=coupons&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/images/([^/]+)$ /index.php?option=com_vendorsearch&view=images&id=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/videos/([^/]+)$ /index.php?option=com_vendorsearch&view=videos&id=$2 [L]
```

Comment: what is the name of the file you want to move and what is the url you want to point it to?  What have you tried, because you appear to just be showing us your full .htacceess file.

Comment: @miah actaully i created some views for the vendorsearch component.I want to show the url of that views as www.example.com/qwerty/articles/article-title.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you need your first rules as:

```
RewriteRule ^[^/]+/articles/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?option=com_vendorsearch&view=article&title=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```